# ¿Por que java no reconoce los cambios en elementos?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un pequeño software con java AWT pero por alguna razon java no reconoce el estado actual de los objetos visuales.
Cosas como `jbutton.isEnabled();` y `jbutton.getText().equals("xxx");` son abiertamente ignorados por los valores por defecto.

[image: Bug java AWT]

Para clarificar:
jButtonExec es el `JButton` que esta deshabilitado pero que según la salida esta habilitado.
jButtonOm es el botón que su texto tiene por valor "Siguiente" pero entiende su valor el texto por defecto Omitir.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque ocurre esto?
Gracias.

Para quien quiera ver lo que se corta por un poco:

```
    public boolean Omitir(StepData dat){
    System.out.println("status:"+this.jButtonExec.isEnabled());
    System.out.println("Text:" +this.jButtonOm.getText());
    if(this.jButtonExec.isEnabled()==true && this.jButtonOm.getText().equals("Siguiente")){
        this.executed.set(dat.getId(), true);
    }
    int aux = NextStepExec(this.actual);
    return true;}
```

Declaraciones pertinentes:

```
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextAreaDes = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jButtonExec = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtonOm = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButtonExito = new javax.swing.JButton();
    
    ...
    
     jButtonExec.setText("Ejecutar");
    jButtonExec.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonExecActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    
    jButtonOm.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonOmActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    
    private void jButtonOmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(this.executed.get(this.actual) == true){
        BTgestion(2);
    }else{
        BTgestion(2);
    }
    Omitir(this.data);
}
```

setTimeout("get_messages();",130);

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon el código como texto. Ni siquiera se ve parte del código problemático en tu captura de pantalla. Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código haciendo un copiar / pegar.

Comment: ¿Las referencias a esos objetos están bien? Muestra cómo defines a `jButtonExec` y a `jButtonOm`. Otra cosa, esto es redundante en una comparación: `this.jButtonExec.isEnabled()==true` si el método devuelve un booleano, basta con ponerlo directamente: **`if(this.jButtonExec.isEnabled() && this.jButtonOm.getText().equals("Siguiente")){`**

Comment: Ese es el problema, si miras la imagen veras que el botón jButtonExec esta deshabilitado pero en el system.out.println("Status:"+ jButtonExec.isEnabled()) devuelve true pese a estar visiblemente deshabilitado. Y lo mismo pasa con jButtonOm que en vez de devolver Siguiente como se ve devuelve su valor por defecto "Omitir."

Comment: Ya, pero puede que tú estés declarando equivocadamente los objetos **`jButtonExec`** y  **`jButtonOm`** en ese contexto. Muestra el código donde declaras esos objetos, así como el contexto donde estás llamando a ese método `Omitir()`.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en el método **`BTgestion()`**, que estás llamando antes de llamar a `Omitir()`? ¿No estarás modificando los botones en ese método?

Comment: No porque el método BTgestion lo que hace es cambiar los textos pero estos ya están cambiados como se ve en la imagen. Si no cambiaran el problema estaria allí.

Comment: No des nada por supuesto. Prueba a comentar las dos llamadas a `BTgestion()`.

Comment: los  `== true` salen sobrando

Comment: si los ==, si sobran solo los he dejado como ayuda visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución mas simple era la correcta.

```
public boolean Omitir(StepData dat)
```

Los botones se ponen en una posición concreta por un tipo de datos en la variable "dat" usando el método BTgestion(n);.
Por ello la solución es ignorar el estado de los botones y usar la variable objeto "dat" como referencia en vez de:

```
if(this.jButtonExec.isEnabled() && this.jButtonOm.getText().equals("Siguiente"))
```

Uso sencillamente:

```
if(dat.getDato() == Tipo de dato){
```

Gracias por vuestro apoyo.